# break .text() into new lines between variables

Tags: jquery

Good afternoon, 
I'm trying to break each variable and checkbox into a new line.

**Current Outcome: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/Hw11TXnI.png** 
Rank Year Rating Gross

**Desired Outcome:**
Rank
Year
Rating
Gross

Thanks in advance. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/73ado6vu/2/

```
    var hasNonPersistentHeaders = false;
    $( this.headers ).not( "td" ).each( function() {
        var $this = $( this ),
            priority = $this.attr("data-tablesaw-priority"),
            $cells = self.$getCells( this );

        if( priority && priority !== "persist" ) {
            $cells.addClass( self.classes.priorityPrefix + priority );

            $("<label><input type='checkbox' value='test' checked>" + $this.text() + "</input></label>" )
                .appendTo( $menu )
                .children( 0 )
                .data( "tablesaw-header", this );

            hasNonPersistentHeaders = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: simply add a <br/> after your input&label?

Comment: no dice, it moves the checkboxes up on the first line and labels on the 2nd line doing that - https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/Hw10BT2.png

Comment: what about changing label to <p>

Comment: same result with the checkboxes on one line and variables on the second =/

Comment: would it be possible to create a fiddle to illustrate your problem

Comment: here you go, sorry about that. http://jsfiddle.net/73ado6vu/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED THIS ANSWER**

I checked the link you sent and I came up with this.
Try doing this CSS:

```
.btn-group {
   display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort unfortunately my page wont load after doing this.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined
    at ColumnToggle.$getCells (tablesaw.js:466)
    at ColumnToggle.$getCellsFromCheckbox (tablesaw.js:471)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (tablesaw.js:477)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:4070)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js:3874)
    at ColumnToggle.refreshToggle (tablesaw.js:476)
    at tablesaw.js:459
    at dispatch (jquery.js:7630)
    at r.handle (jquery.js:7307)

Comment: Can you change your html to reflect the change in the statement I created? I mean, can you also add `<div class="checkbox">...</div>` on the part you are referencing in the `$(...)` code in your jquery?

Comment: Or it is better if you can show us your html in this part so we can diagnose properly :)

Comment: Check the  new answer.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for your help and time :D

Comment: Any chance you know a way to easily add a max limit to the dropdown before making it scroll?

Comment: As I tried it, it does not scroll. Maybe you could post this as another question for others to answer :)